# Android: Heart Rate BPM sound playing

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

For my application I need to replicate the beeping of a heart rate monitor, that is, it plays a sound N times every minute. The problem is that it seems to lag by about 5ms. I know I can't expect realtime performance because of context switching on the OS and other overhead. With a BPM of 80, I get the following log output:

```
MainActivity: Beeping every 946ms

MainActivity: java.lang.InterruptedException

MainActivity: Beep 0: 951
MainActivity: Beep 1: 951
MainActivity: Beep 2: 951
MainActivity: Beep 3: 951
MainActivity: Beep 4: 951
MainActivity: Beep 5: 951
MainActivity: Beep 6: 952
MainActivity: Beep 7: 951
MainActivity: Beep 8: 954
MainActivity: Beep 9: 951
MainActivity: Beep 10: 953
MainActivity: Beep 11: 952
MainActivity: Beep 12: 951
MainActivity: Beep 13: 951
```

Here is my `Thread` that I use to play the beep sound:

```
mBeepThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<Long> beepTimes = new ArrayList<Long>(5000);
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                afd = getAssets().openFd("audio/heart_beep.ogg");
                SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(10,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);

                int soundId = sp.load(afd, 1);
                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                long duration = mp.getDuration();
                long waitTime = (60000/bpmVal) - duration;
                mp.release();
                Log.i(TAG,"Beeping every "+waitTime+"ms");
                while(true) {
                    beepTimes.add(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    sp.play(soundId,1,1,1,0,1); 
                    Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
                Iterator<Long> it = beepTimes.iterator();
                int count = 0;
                Long oldTime = it.next();
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    long newTime = it.next();
                    long diff =  newTime - oldTime;
                    oldTime = newTime;
                    Log.i(TAG,String.format("Beep %d: %d",count++,diff));
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    mBeepThread.start();
```

Is there anything I can do to make it play true to the set BPM or is it actually playing every 946ms and the other 5 are just overhead from making the sound play and logging?

I know I could take off 5ms from `waitTime`, but that feels like cheating and not solving the actual problem.

Comment: There are probably some overheads to calling play but the larger problem is that `Thread.sleep` doesn't have any realtime guarantees. It is subject to the whims of the scheduler.

Comment: @jaket well then how do you propose I implement a beep every `n` ms then?

Comment: Well if it were me I'd be synchronizing to the audio clock rather than the system clock. I mean, could you imagine a drum machine or a DAW with Thread.sleeps all over the place? Unfortunately, the only proper way to do it is to output a bunch of zeros to the output until the exact sample when you need the beep to play and then output that.

Comment: That sounds like you'd still be doing a lot of busy waiting, ie: `while(true)if(getTime() - lastPlay >= waitTime) {audioTrack.write(soundBuffer);lastPlay = getTime();} else audioTrack.write(0);`

Comment: Not necessarily. Most APIs either use a callback or have blocking calls. Busy waiting is not the issue though. If you want to time audio events accurately then, as you can see in your experiment, sleep is not going to do it.

Comment: @jaket Can you give a reference implementation that implements this then? I watched a google I/O talk on low latency sound but it didn't give any sort of implementation details (which they said to refer to). Do I have to use OpenSL?

Comment: Try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is similar in nature to many that have been asked before concerning implementation of a metronome.

THe only way to achieve this accurately is to render your own PCM stream.  Since the system (wall) clock is not synchronous with the audio clock, you cannot reliably use this to insert your periodic events - none of the available ways of doing this (e.g sleeping a dedicated thread, using timers) are accurate enough as they all rely on accurate scheduling and/or the run loop to not be congested.

Instead you insert the event after every N samples are rendered into the PCM stream, where N is a function of the period and sample-rate.

Comment: Can you give a code example of how this is achieved, I read the other questions, and nobody gave any code or linked to how to do this.

Comment: Sorry - not got one to hand for Android. Even for iOS where I do, it's quite a lot of code.